# spark: split only one column in dataframe and keep remaining columns as it is

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I am reading the file in spark dataframe.
In the first column, I will get two values concatenated with "_".
I need to split the first column into two columns and keep the remaining columns as it is. I am using Scala with Spark

For example:

```
col1  col2   col3

a_1    xyz   abc

b_1    lmn   opq
```

I need to have new DF as:

```
col1_1  col1_2  col2  col3

a       1       xyz   abc

b       1       lmn   opq
```

only one column needs to be split into two columns.

I tried with split function with df.select but I need to write the select for remaining columns and considering different files with 100's of columns and I want to use the reusable code for all files.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
import spark.implicits._

df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"col1", "_"))
 .withColumn("col1_1", $"_tmp".getItem(0))
 .withColumn("col1_2", $"_tmp".getItem(1))
 .drop("_tmp")
```